# how to focus on button while typing on text box

Tags: c#-4.0

**if I had a text box and a button.if I typed a letter in text box then the control has to be automatically focus on the button.so that when I hit enter the code under the button will execute **

```
   I tried  button1.focus();// in text box but it transfering the control to button so that I cant able to type in text box.
```

Comment: You need to set the default property of the button. How you do that depends on what platform (web, windows forms?) you are targetting

Comment: windows form @podiluska

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Select the form on which the button resides.
2.In the Properties window, set the form's **AcceptButton** property to the Button control's name.